# C Network Programming - Winsock

Tags: c, networking, winsock

I have been learning C over the last two weeks, managed to get my head around pointers, arrays and structures.

I am looking to do a bit of socket programming on windows and was wondering if anyone has any websites with tutorials and examples or suggest books that teach network programming with winsock?

I have tried looking for some but all seem to be aimed at towards linux/unix.

Cheers

Eef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not a tutorial exactly, the [Winsock Programmer's FAQ](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/) has tutorial elements, and it will answer the questions you'll have as you learn Winsock programming.

*Disclaimer: I'm the FAQ's maintainer.*

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't get any better than [Beej](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)!

He addresses Windows in particular in [this section](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/intro.html#windows).

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at [microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's pretty well done